# Replacement Stylus for Stanton STR8-100

Tags: turntables

I've just won my first set of turntables on eBay, a pair of Stanton STR8-100's.

The seller has informed me one of the decks needs a replacement stylus.

As I'm new to this, I'm not sure what I need to buy.

Do I search for Stanton Stylus? Stanton Cartridge? And how do I know which will fit my deck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any cartridge will do. It's up to you if you want to try and source a stylus, or get a new cartridge. I personally would buy 2 new cartridges (1 for each). They should be a standard fit, just unscrew the old carts, and pop in the new.

Comment: Cheers I didn't realise that it was possible to connect any standard cartridge, I thought I'd have to buy one specific for my turntables. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You'd want to search for "Stanton STR8-100 cartridge" or "Stanton STR8-100 stylus".

Will you be scratching?  You will go through stylii faster and would probably want an [MM (moving magnet) cartridge versus an MC (moving coil) cartridge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_cartridge#Moving_Magnet_.28MM.29_and_Moving_Iron_.28MI.29_cartridges).

Comment: I will just be doing straight forward mixing, no actual scratching